# HTML5 Header Hierarchy

Tags: html, hierarchy

I have got just a quick question regarding the header hierarchy when using HTML5 and especially sections. I am asking from a SEO point of view.

At this moment my markup looks like this:

```
<article>

<header><h1>Article Header</h1></header>
<!-- Bla bla -->
<section>
<header><h1>Article section 1</h1></header>
<!-- Bla bla -->
</section>

<section>
<header><h1>Article section 2</h1></header>
<!-- Bla bla -->
<h2>Article section 2 Sub 1</h2>
<!-- Bla bla -->
</section>

<section>
<header><h1>Article section 3</h1></header>
<!-- Bla bla -->
</section>

</article>
```

The questions I am asking is about `<h1>Article section 2</h1>` and `<h1>Article section 3</h1>` and the code in-between.

Its [outline](https://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/) is as expected:

[hmtl5 outline http://i51.tinypic.com/34pi1hk.jpg](http://i51.tinypic.com/34pi1hk.jpg)

But when looking at the site without css, I am seeing this:
[image: no css]

As you can see in the second picture it seems that `<h2>Article section 2 Sub 1</h2>` is given more "importance", although it is just a `h2` of another subsection (just like displayed in the outline).

Now I am wondering if I can safely ignore this, or does Google probably also think that `<h2>Article section 2 Sub 1</h2>` is more important than the previous and next `h1` titles? Obviously, I want to make sure that `<h2>Article section 2 Sub 1</h2>` is given less importance than the previous and next `h1` titles.

I hope I was able to explain what I am trying to figure out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, HTML5 is backward-compatible with HTML4.

- You can use old style h2+ tags
- Or just sectioning contents and the h1 tag only
- Or both, in the same page!

but default style is firstly made to maintain backward compatibility with older pages,
then to implement html5-sectioning's default style

- Your code is not wrong, you just need to reset the style.

I'm pretty sure about this because I've read some discussions on mozilla's bugzilla

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi! Ok, so if I get what you are saying: the h2 tag just gets rendered bigger, because of the backward compatibility and it renders it as a html4 page? But than why are the h1 tags rendered so small - they should be even bigger if it was a html4 page. Anyways: so what I was trying to figure out: will Google see that the h2 tag is a subheader of a subsection and therefor is less important than the h1 tags surrounding it?

Comment: because only h1 is considered a valid html5 heading, so if it is placed inside a section, it takes the new html5 style read this: http://nopaste.voric.com/paste.php?f=ketou8 and yes, your outline is correct, you just need to set up your style

Comment: Sorry if I am slow today, but what do you mean with setup styles? Of course I am using css to style my headers, but I did disable styles on purpose to get a better idea of my site structure and there (with no styles enabled) the h2 tag is rendered bigger. Thats why I think its given more importance. And I am worried Google will think that way too.

Comment: As I said, but probably without a good English, your outline is correct, google will not give more importance to h2. trust me. <h2></h2> is totally equivalent to <section><h1></h1></section>

Comment: @wes. "because only h1 is considered a valid html5 heading". That's just nonsense, and the linked style sheet is just lazy and buggy. The reality is that generic style sheets just haven't yet caught up with the HTML5 outlining algorithm.

Comment: Okay! Thanks a lot for your patience! one last thing: you said its equal to "<section><h1></h1></section>" - did you maybe mean it is less important? (The outline shows it correctly as sub header of the current section and therefor less important[?]) Or would I have to change it to h3/h4 to make it really less important?

Comment: are totally equivalent: <body><section><section><h1>a</h1><p>aaa</p></section><h2>b</h2><p>bbb</p></section></body> the style is not responsive, but the "a" and the "b" are placed at the same level in the outline

Comment: @Alohci it is not lazy and buggy, before talk, document yourself, it is the firefox's and webkit's default style for sections' titles, not some my crazy idea

Comment: @wes - I didn't mean to imply it was your idea, or that I was getting at you in any way, except possibly being a little too trusting of what you have read. It is definitely buggy, even if it's standard Gecko and Webkit. Lazy is somewhat more subjective. It is, admittedly, not easy to replicate the outline algorithm in css selectors, but IMHO they could have tried a little harder.

Comment: ... or even a little less hard, and not tried to replicate the algorithm at all. What they ended up with is a pointless and confusing middle ground.

Comment: I am gonna mark this answer although Rob just gave me a short answer to what I was trying to ask, but since my question was bad written, you took a bit longer to get what i was trying to ask :) But in the end you both said that h2 will be given less importance.

Answer (score 1):

The order of rendering the page never means anything as far as SEO is concerned. h1 will always be given more importance compared to h2 in the context it is placed in.

Comment: Thanks for that insight! I actually thought when a browser renders a specific title bigger than another one (without css and styles), it means that it somehow gives it more "importance". You just answered my question, but I hope you dont mind when I accept wes´ answer, since he has taken so much time to answer to my foolish questions. I´d mark both if possible!

Comment: the h2 is not bigger because it is more important, it is bigger because, basically, the browser uses the HTML4 style.